# nginx - validate subjectAltName or extKeyUsage

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

We are doing the mTLS enforced with `ssl_verify_client: "optional"` and using `if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {` way to check that the client certificate is provided or not. However, how do we validate the client certificate as part of the mTLS handshake like, checking that below dns under "subjectAltName" is not null or clienthAuth" under "extKeyUsage" is not null ? is ther a way to accomplish this in nginx config or nginx-ingress ?

```
  subjectAltName :
    dns: acme0001.example001.helloworld.com
    dns: acme.helloworld.com
  extKeyUsage :
    clientAuth, 1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.2.2.2, serverAuth
```